# SQLite data results round off decimals in .NET, shows correct results in DB Browser for SQLite

Tags: wpf, sqlite, datatable

I am running a query in my WPF application utilizing .NET data connector for SQLite which shows different results as compared to running the same exact query in DB Browser for SQLite. The results of DB Browser are correct. Basically the decimals are rounded off in WPF application.

SQL Query:

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(qty), 0) AS qty, IFNULL(SUM(amount), 0) AS amount, IFNULL(SUM(fat*qty), 0) AS avgfat, IFNULL(SUM(snf*qty), 0) AS avgsnf, IFNULL(SUM(pd1amount+pd2amount+pd3amount), 0) AS pd, IFNULL(COUNT(shift+Date), 0) AS shiftcount, milktype, ledgerid, ledgeralias, ledgername 
FROM vouchercollections 
WHERE ledgeralias>=1 AND ledgeralias<=100 AND membertype<>'C' 
AND date>='2019-07-25 00:00:00' AND date<='2019-07-25 23:59:59'
GROUP BY milktype, ledgerid, ledgeralias, ledgername 
ORDER BY ledgeralias, milktype desc
```

Results in Data Visualizer in DataTable. At this stage no manual data manipulation has happened, these are results straight from query to DataTable.

[image]

Results from DB Browser for SQLite

[image]

If you look at row no. 2 and 3, the quantity is 6 and 12 in DataTable and 5.5 and 12.5 in DB Browser for SQLite.

What could be wrong?

Update 2019-07-25: It appears that if the first result in the query is a decimal, the entire returned table is correct. However, if the first result is a whole number, the entire result set is whole numbers.

Comment: What's the type of qty column in the data table?

Comment: NUMERIC. Although SQLite does not seem to care much about data types. For eg, you can save text in integer fields!

Answer (score 1):

I confirm your update : it depends on the first values return by the query !
Which is a pain.

The only workaround I found so far is to force with `a : 1.00 * field`

In your example : `"SELECT IFNULL(SUM(1.00 * qty), 0) AS qty"` should work.

If anybody has a more systematic solution, I'm interested.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I will test your solution and post the results.